# swift - AWS DynamoDB not scanning properly

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm developing an app in Swift and using DynamoDB for my database.

When scanning the database, when I print the attributes, they are returned as nil, however, nil is printed the amount of times a record appears following the query. If I change the query to something that has no values in the table, nothing is printed.

How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.EUWest2, identityPoolId:"*redacted*")

let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.EUWest2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

let cognitoId = credentialsProvider.identityId

var dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
scanExpression.indexName = "city2"
scanExpression.filterExpression = "city = :cityName"
scanExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":cityName": "london"]

dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(AWSLineStatus.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

    if task.result != nil {
        let paginatedOutput = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput               
        print("Items: \(paginatedOutput.items)")

        for item in paginatedOutput.items as! [AWSLineStatus] {
            print(item.line as Any)
        }

        if ((task.error) != nil) {
            print("Error: \(task.error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
    return nil
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Dumb question: Do your database entries actually have attribute `line` set? i.e. Do you see a value for `line` in the DynamoDB console?

Comment: Yeah, all attributes are correct. The same happens when I use any of the attributes.